# SQL Update command with various variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have table like:

**Items**

- ID(int)
- Name(varchar)
- Date(DateTime)
- Value(int)

I would like to write SQL Command which will update only these values, which are not null

Pseudo code of what I would like to do:

```
UPDATE Items
SET 
  IF @NewName IS NOT NULL
  {
    Items.Name = @NewName
  }
  IF @NewDate IS NOT NULL
  {
    Items.Date = @NewDate
  }
  IF @newValue IS NOT NULL
  {
    Items.Valie = @NewValue
  }
WHERE Items.ID = @ID
```

Is it possible to write query like this?

Comment: I would probably do a separate query for each column, since you only have 3. `UPDATE Items SET Name=@NewName WHERE Name=null` and then do the next one, `UPDATE Items SET Date=@NewDate WHERE Date=null`. It's not a reusable or extensible solution, but it would work for a one-off scenario.

Comment: @Adam That has the overhead of taking a lock 3 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Items
SET Name    = ISNULL(@NewName,Name),
    [Date]  = ISNULL(@NewDate,[Date]),
    Value   = ISNULL(@NewValue,Value)
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannt use if statement in  update you can use below query for update on condition

```
'UPDATE Items
SET 
Items.Name = (case when @NewName is not null then @NewName else  end) ,
Items.Date = (case when  @NewDate is not null then @newDate else end ),
Items.Valie = (case when  @Valie is not null then @Valie else  end )
```

WHERE Items.ID = @ID'

Answer (score -2):

You can make something like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)

set @sql = 'UPDATE Items SET '

IF @NewName IS NOT NULL
    @sql = @sql + 'Items.Name = ' + @NewName

IF @NewDate IS NOT NULL
    @sql = @sql + 'Items.Date = ' + @NewDate

IF @newValue IS NOT NULL
    @sql = @sql + 'Items.Valie = ' + @NewValue

@sql = @sql + 'WHERE Items.ID = ' + @ID

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: You are making quite the assumption in your answer. I would say it's far more probable that `@NewDate` is a `DATETIME` instead of a string

Comment: This introduces SQL injection possibilities.